# How to select form field by NAME complicate value

Tags: javascript, jquery

im using one web app where i can't edit html code, just can add js script.
And i need there to change some form fields. The issue is, they don't have any ID, only NAME values and they have extremely strange format.. And i don't know how can i select them with JS code..

This is form field i need to select

```
<input type="text" name="params[content][alias_translation][en-GB]" value="">
```

This is example of my code (works if NAME value is simple)

```
jQuery(function() {                               
jQuery("[name=something]").change(function() { ... });
});
```

This is what i try but this don't work

```
jQuery(function() {                               
jQuery("[name=params[content][alias_translation][en-GB]]").change(function() { ... });
});
```

Anyone please know how can i select this strange field?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use quotes:

```js
jQuery("[name='params[content][alias_translation][en-GB]']")
```